# Differing Y Scale Between Two Limits

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I would like to create a scatter plot that has only one Y-axis but on that axis has two scales set between different limits.

The reason being, I have data that is densely populated near zero, but also has points that reach up to 2500. I would like to show some of the distribution of points below 100, without cutting off the data near the top.

Other suggestions for accomplishing this are welcome.

I have also tried using a log scale. This accomplishes what I would like to show.

```
# scatter plot
sp<-ggplot(cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) + geom_point()
```

For example: I would like to use a scale that increments from 0 to 10 on the y axis have the same spacing as 0 to 25 shown here. And then the next tick marks increment from 25 to 50 with equal spacing as the distance from 0 to 10.
[image: a busy cat]

I hope I made this as clear as possible.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Edit...

Hi. Sorry, I misunderstood your original post. I don't know of a way to do exactly what you are looking for. It sounds like it would be difficult to customise the y-axis to that extent but maybe others on this site may know a way.

Reading your comment about the log-transformation, there is a way to show the data in it's transformed state but retaining the original labels on the y-axis. Maybe this would be the simplest way of formatting this graph for you.

Please see the section [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-axis-scales-and-transformations) about axis transformations. Applying this to your code above:

```
sp<-ggplot(cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) + geom_point() +  scale_y_log10()
```

This will give a chart as per below. I hope that's useful for you.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't think I made myself quite clear, or it is an impossible request. I would like the spacing between 0-10 to cover the same area as the spacing from 0-25 in the picture i posted. Then the breaks should be at say, 50,75, and 100 but cover the same area as the rectangle from 0-10.

Answer (score 0):

This is not quit exactly that, but make some similar trick:

```
ggplot(cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) + geom_point() + 
  scale_x_sqrt()
```

[image]